# How replace/set caller class loader?

Tags: java, class, classloader

Is it possible to "set" class loader that returns from `ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader()`? And use it as caller class loader when [Class.forName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is called?

Comment: Does Thread#setContextClassLoader help?

Comment: No. Thread#setContextClassLoader does not help.